# Output to a web server from VB.net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms

I have a WinForm VB application that outputs RGB colors to the display while collecting measurements through a USB-connected colorimeter. Works great. But I would like to output the same RGB colors to a web browser instead. The goal of my application is to collects over 200 measurements off the display. My research, so far, on how to possibly do this haven't uncovered anything conclusive. I don't need to upload files just some RGB triplets for the server to display smack in the center of the screen. No need for advance button or interaction, everything ought to be controlled by my application. One options is to use the resource of an IIS web server which I have access to. The problem I have is that I have a hard time conceptualizing the kinds of communication I have to establish with Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge or IE in order to successively display 200 colors, one by one, while my instrument, running on a laptop, takes 2 to 3 seconds readings at a time? I wish I could sit at any computer, launch the browser on a client computer I want to measure colors off, have it point to my web server on the internet, change seat, launch my VB.net application on my laptop and start measuring : my VB.net code communicates with the IIS server and, somehow, the (ASP.net?) pages are updated, one by one, nothing fancy, just a simple square filled with some RGB color combination. That's it. Is that ever possible? How do I approach such a beast?

Answer (score 0):

Web sites aren't great for this sort of thing.  They are primarily designed to respond to the browser's request for a page; pushing data *to* the page needs some advanced techniques (e.g. using something like [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)).

The alternative to pushing data to the page is to program the page to *poll* the server at a preset interval.  If this is good enough for your purposes, here is a step by step on how to get there:

1. Change your VB application that displays data into a DLL that makes data available via an API.
2. Create an empty web project in Visual Studio
3. Add a reference to your VB DLL
4. Write a simple page that uses the API to obtain the current RBG values and puts them on the page.
5. Add a [meta-refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag to the simple page that causes the browser to re-request the page every second or so.

Comment: Thank's a lot, John. I was thinking, perhaps, to have a "timer" of some sort, on the web page, where it would refresh at a certain interval, corresponding to my measurement time. I'm not sure how that can be done in code behind? I'll look into the meta-refresh tag...